# How to unserialize a JSON data in a tpl file in Smarty?

Tags: php, arrays, json, smarty

I need your help with my problem. I am new in smarty and I am having a hard time finding a solution with my problem. Ok here's my problem.

I have an array that is formatted to JSON and it is serialize. What I want is to unserialize it and extract the array value.

What I did is I assign the serialize data into a variable and the next is unserialize it but it doesn't display my data.

Here's my code:

```
{assign var="type" value="$product.employment_type"}
{$type|unserialize} {**doesn't display my data**}
```

Here's my sample output in serialize:

```
a:2:{i:0;s:8:"fulltime";i:1;s:8:"contract";}
```

Here's the array form:

```
Array
(
    [0] => fulltime
    [1] => contract
)
```

The next problem is display the array values.

My sample output should be:

```
fulltime, contract
```

That's all guys I hope you can help me.

Comment: I haven't feeded Smarty with JSON - yet. Is there any reason why you're doing it this way? Since you are almost certainly accessing Smarty with a php script, why not `json_decode()` your JSON and assign the resulting array to your Smarty templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $product.employment_type returns the string "a:2{i:0;s:8:"fulltime";i:1;s:8:"contract";}", you could try the following:

```
{assign var=type value=$product.employment_type|unserialize}
{$type.0}, {$type.1}
```

Or you could also try:

```
{foreach from=$product.employment_type|unserialize item=type}
    {$type}
{/foreach}
```